# How to read an HTML cookie in Flash?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, cookies

I'm hoping to get pointed in the right direction here. The problem I'm having is trying to figure out how to read an HTML created cookie in Flash. I have a video player that should autoplay once in a 24hour period, the next day it should autoplay again for the end-user.

This is what the script on the HTML page looks like that displays the Flash player and the cookie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("flvplayer.swf", "mymovie", "640", "394", "8", "#90ab69");
var x = readCookie('homepageIntro') // <- The Cookie (How do I read this in Flash?)
so.addParam("quality", "high");
so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
so.useExpressInstall('expressinstall.swf');
so.addVariable("autostart", "false");
so.addVariable("file", "video.flv");
so.addVariable("key", "");
so.addVariable("showfsbutton", "false");
so.addVariable("noControls", "false");
so.addVariable("home", "true");
so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

Not knowing how to read that `var x` inside of Flash, I tried to get around having to use it by using a Flash cookie, however now the video player will only ever autoplay once and never ever autoplay again(unable to clear the Flash cookie).

```
public function sharedObjectCheck():void
{
    if (mySharedObject.data.flashCookie == "true"){
        //Code to NOT autoplay video
    } else if (mySharedObject.data.flashCookie == null){
        mySharedObject.data.flashCookie = "true"; //if first time, set the cookie value
        mySharedObject.flush(); //add the cookie
    }
}
```

I did some searching and found this [Have a HTML page play Flash movie only once (not when revisited…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108549/have-a-html-page-play-flash-movie-only-once-not-when-revisited) but again this is just a Flash function which never allows for a restart in a certain time period.

So my question to my fellow Flash stackers is how do I read that `var x`*(cookie)* in Flash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct answer to your question is to use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

```
import flash.external.*

try {
  var cookie : String = ExternalInterface.call("readCookie", "homepageIntro") as String;
} catch (error : SecurityError) {
  trace("SecurityError:", e.message);
} catch (error : Error) {
  trace("Error:", e.message);
}
```

You likely also need to set [allowScriptAccess](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html) to let the call run.

Using a LSO is probably your best option, or passing in the value of `x` as a FlashVar.

Comment: hey thanks, going to setup a test for this. Btw I'm getting an Syntax error warning in Flash on the e.message lines, so I'm just taking out that part.

Comment: It should be fixed now.  The traces were missing commas.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried assigning the x value to flashvars?

```
so.addVariable("cookie", x);
```

In which case , you should be able to retrieve it in Flash , by doing so in the Document Class:

```
var params:Object = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
var cookie:Object = params.cookie;
```

Comment: I have to wait for the HTML guy to update that code, unfortunately updating the frontend code is in a system I don't get into :/ also delaying my testing of Tylers answer, but yes I like moving that value into the FlashVars much better...

Comment: On another note, the SWFObject code doesn't seem up to date , I don't think the current SWFObject version ( 2.2 ) still supports the addVariable method...

Comment: Yeah, the OP looks like he is using SWFObject 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a flash cookie, but actually store the last time autoplayed, rather than a simple flag.

Comment: Hmm so something like check client's local time, save it in the sharedObject, then when the check is run again do a kinda 24hour difference calculation? Or is there an easier way to do that with sharedObject?